# Why is everything centered in the GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to build a table look with the GridBagLayout, but it keeps centering everything.
I don't know why it is doing this. My insets are set at 5, yet it makes them look huge.

It started off fine, but somewhere it changed to do this. I cant ctrl + z to go back.

Here is my code:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

panelInfo = new JPanel();
scrollPane.setViewportView(panelInfo);
GridBagLayout gbl_panelInfo = new GridBagLayout();
gbl_panelInfo.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
gbl_panelInfo.rowHeights = new int[] {0, 30, 0};
gbl_panelInfo.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
gbl_panelInfo.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
panelInfo.setLayout(gbl_panelInfo);

JLabel lblColumnName1 = new JLabel("No.");
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblColumnName1 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lblColumnName1.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_lblColumnName1.gridx = 0;
gbc_lblColumnName1.gridy = 0;
panelInfo.add(lblColumnName1, gbc_lblColumnName1);

JLabel lblColumnName2 = new JLabel("Name");
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblColumnName2 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lblColumnName2.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_lblColumnName2.gridx = 1;
gbc_lblColumnName2.gridy = 0;
panelInfo.add(lblColumnName2, gbc_lblColumnName2);

JLabel lblColumnName3 = new JLabel("Number");
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblColumnName3 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lblColumnName3.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_lblColumnName3.gridx = 2;
gbc_lblColumnName3.gridy = 0;
panelInfo.add(lblColumnName3, gbc_lblColumnName3);

JLabel lblColumnName4 = new JLabel("Credits");
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblColumnName4 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lblColumnName4.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_lblColumnName4.gridx = 3;
gbc_lblColumnName4.gridy = 0;
panelInfo.add(lblColumnName4, gbc_lblColumnName4);

JLabel lblColumnName5 = new JLabel("Grade");
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblColumnName5 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lblColumnName5.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 0);
gbc_lblColumnName5.gridx = 4;
gbc_lblColumnName5.gridy = 0;
panelInfo.add(lblColumnName5, gbc_lblColumnName5);          
        


ArrayList<Course> courseList = user.getCourseList();
if(courseList.size() == 0) lblMessage.setText("Student has never enrolled in any course");

int i = 1, x= 0;
Double total = 0d;
if(courseList.size() > 0) {
for(; i < courseList.size() + 1; i++) {
    JLabel lblRowData1 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(i));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblRowData1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblRowData1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblRowData1.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblRowData1.gridy = i;
    panelInfo.add(lblRowData1, gbc_lblRowData1);
    
    JLabel lblRowData2 = new JLabel(courseList.get(i-1).getName());
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblRowData2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblRowData2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblRowData2.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblRowData2.gridy = i;
    panelInfo.add(lblRowData2, gbc_lblRowData2);
    
    JLabel lblRowData3 = new JLabel(courseList.get(i-1).getNumber());
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblRowData3 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblRowData3.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblRowData3.gridx = 2;
    gbc_lblRowData3.gridy = i;
    panelInfo.add(lblRowData3, gbc_lblRowData3);
    
    JLabel lblRowData4 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(courseList.get(i-1).getCredits()));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblRowData4 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblRowData4.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblRowData4.gridx = 3;
    gbc_lblRowData4.gridy = i;
    panelInfo.add(lblRowData4, gbc_lblRowData4);
    
    Double grade = user.getGrades().get(i-1);
    total += grade;
    x++;
    JLabel lblRowData5 = new JLabel(String.format("%.2f", grade));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblRowData5 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblRowData5.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblRowData5.gridx = 4;
    gbc_lblRowData5.gridy = i;
    panelInfo.add(lblRowData5, gbc_lblRowData5);
}
}

JLabel lblGPA = new JLabel("GPA: ");
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblGPA = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lblGPA.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
gbc_lblGPA.gridx = 3;
gbc_lblGPA.gridy = i+1;
panelInfo.add(lblGPA, gbc_lblGPA);


JLabel lblGPAvalue = new JLabel(String.format("%.2f", total/x));
GridBagConstraints gbc_lblGPAvalue = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lblGPAvalue.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc_lblGPAvalue.gridx = 4;
gbc_lblGPAvalue.gridy = i+1;
panelInfo.add(lblGPAvalue, gbc_lblGPAvalue);
numOfCoursesDisplayed = x;
```

[image]

I have the exact same code in another class of the same project, over there its fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the `anchor` field in `GridBagConsraints` to `TOP`;

If you want the look of the table, why not just use a `JTable`? It would be a much cleaner look and easier to deal with.

Comment: Plus one for the 2nd paragraph re using a `JTable`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by applying the following changes:

```
GridBagLayout gbl_panelInfo = new GridBagLayout();
gbl_panelInfo.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
gbl_panelInfo.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
gbl_panelInfo.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gbl_panelInfo.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
panelInfo.setLayout(gbl_panelInfo);
```